# How to add new item to array or object

Tags: php, arrays

This is my code. I want to add new key or item in array or object. I am adding previewImage key to images array in foreach loop. But it not success. When I print images array it display correctly. But when I print out of foreach it not contain previewImage key.

```
if(!empty($scope) && $scope == "productList"){
        $productList = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM products");

        foreach($productList as $key => $value){

            $images = (array) $value;
            $images['previewImage'] = $fileUploadDir."/products/".$images['image'];

            print_r($images['previewImage']);
            //$value = (object) $images;
        }
        print_r($productList);
        if($productList){
            $response = array('status' => true, 'message' => 'Product success.', data => $productList);
        } else addResponse(false, "product error", "null");
```

Please give me solution...

Comment: check `if($productList){` as `if(is_array($productList)){` and change `data => $productList` to `'data' => $productList`

Comment: @Choldas are you asking about `print_r($productList);` not having previewImage

Comment: Yes. I want to add previewImage key  as `$productList[][$value]['previewImage '] ` in that array and store imagepath.

Comment: You are adding key 'previewImage' and value $images['image'] to the $images array and not to the $productList array.  That is why it prints within foreach and not outside it.  That statement should be exactly the way you want it - $productList[][$value]['previewImage '] = $fileUploadDir."/products/".$images['image'];

Comment: I already used this $productList[][$value]['previewImage '] = $fileUploadDir."/products/".$images['image']; But it gives Error like as "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array";